# Kubectl Unable to connect to the server with i/o timeout error

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to solve this problem below:

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.6", GitCommit:"dff82dc0de47299ab66c83c626e08b245ab19037", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-07-15T16:58:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.0.10:6443: i/o timeout
```

And i found answer on some stackoverflow post that i am trying to solve

```
$kubectl config view 
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://192.168.0.10:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

And after that i wrote following command and got this below:

```
$ kubectl config use-context docker-for-desktop
error: no context exists with the name: "docker-for-desktop"
```

And after that i'am running sudo docker ps and i get this picture below:

[image]

How can I solve the `Unable to connect to the server` error??

Comment: how ddi you install Kubernetes? Is it local Minikube or installed in some remote server?

Comment: @Arghya Sadhu I installed with this link https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Comment: @Arghya Sadhu Do i use kubectl cluster-info?

Comment: @Arghya SadhuI tried this command as a root netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':6443' and got nothing back??

Comment: from where you are running `kubectl version` ? from master or worker or some other machine?

Comment: @Argya Sadhu I just run it from my Ubuntu Terminal? How can i check where i am running kubectl version?

Comment: Is that the same ubuntu system where you installed kubernetes ? Edit your question to add output of `sudo docker ps`

Comment: @Argha Sadhu Yes i think so? And i edit the question and gave a pic after i typed the sudo docker ps command?

Comment: @Argya Sadhu Yes i did?

Comment: @Argya Sadhu how do i change it to master?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218143/discussion-between-arghya-sadhu-and-mire12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.0.10:6443: i/o timeout`

Above error means Kubernetes API Server which is supposed to listen on port `6443` is not running for issue in `kubeadm init` process. This can be verified by checking if a kube API Server container is running or not by `sudo docker ps | grep api`

Disable swap and reboot machine

```
sudo swapoff -a 
sudo sed -i '/ swap / s/^/#/' /etc/fstab
```

Uninstall and reinstall kubernetes by running below command

```
sudo kubeadm reset -f
sudo kubeadm init
```

As a sidenote if you are trying kubernetes on a local system I suggest to use minikube or kind instead of kubeadm.

Answer (score 0):

Running sudo systemctl restart networking may resolve as well, without reinstall kubernetes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).